# Cannot resolve method 'findViewById(int)' in @Nullable fragment

Tags: java, button, floating, findviewbyid

I am trying to implement a button into a fragment in order to use the Float Action Button (FAB) in order to view the snackbar. How do I link the fab1 to a button in a fragment? this is the `.java` file:

```
public class PrimaryFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.primary_layout,null);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab1);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Hai, Hallo", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

**findViewById** is defined in **Activity** not **Fragment**.

Try this:

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab1);
```